# How do I create a pie chart in Matplotlib using a dataframe, and use the categorical variables in a column as labels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

As the question stated, I want to create a pie chart of the `variable total_product_line` and use the categorical variables in `df['product_line']` as labels. I know I could create a list of the labels, but wouldn't it be a lot more efficient to do it something like this?

```
total_product_line = df.groupby('product_line')[['total']].sum()
plt.pie(total_product_line, labels=df['product_line'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Check [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687789/how-do-i-create-a-pie-chart-using-categorical-data-in-matplotlib). If that isn't an answer to your question, set up a [small complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to use the index of the grouped dataframe for the labels, to ensure that both values and labels have the same number of entries in the same order. E.g. `plt.pie(total_product_line['total'], labels=total_product_line.index)`.  Pandas provides a shortcut via `total_product_line.plot.pie()`.